# "Not a 'subtype' error" when calling function

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I am attempting to load a plist that contains a rather large dictionary, shuffle it, and then save the shuffled version for use in the app. I think I'm close but I'm getting a type casting error, 'NSArray is not a subtype of NSMutableArray', when trying to set `experiments = shuffleArray(experiments)`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
var experiments = NSMutableArray()
var menuIndex = 0

override init() {
    super.init()
    // Create the data model.
    func shuffleArray<T>(var array: Array<T>) -> Array<T>
    {
        for var index = array.count - 1; index > 0; index--
        {
            // Random int from 0 to index-1
            var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1)))

            // Swap two array elements
            // Notice '&' required as swap uses 'inout' parameters
            swap(&array[index], &array[j])
        }
        return array
    }
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("experiments", ofType: "plist") {
        if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
            experiments.addObjectsFromArray(dict.objectForKey("experiments") as NSArray)

            experiments = shuffleArray(experiments)
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return `Array<T>` from shuffleArray, but `Array<T>` is not a subtype of `NSMutableArray`, so you can't assign it to the `experiments` variable.

If you really need generics, you should use `Array<T>` for both of them (unless you have a heterogenic array with different types of objects, but this is very rare and you should think carefully if it is what you want).

Assuming you know that all types are e.g. Int, String or some custom type (say class Experiment), you should use typed array, i.e. `Array<Int>` or `Array<String>` or `Array<Experiment>` for `experiments` and only use generic form `Array<T>` for shuffleArray.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm trying it out now but I'm not sure how to implement your suggestion to use Array<T> for "experiments". Could you provide guidance?

Comment: This more or less got me there. I ended up doing NSMutableArray in the shuffle func. Thank you for your help, Teemu!

Comment: Glad if it helped. It seems that if you need NSArray and NSMutableArray that your array contained either objects of unknown type that you cast later or it contained objects of multiple types. In other cases you should be able to cast it directly.